# i get this error while working on project with nav bar menu in different screen sizes "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, foreach, typeerror

Here is my code of javascript where the error occurs.

```
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {

        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
        
        navLinks.array.forEach((link, index) => {
            if(link.style.animation)
            {
                link.style.animation = '';
            }
            else
            {
                link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 1.5}s`;
            }
        });
                  
        burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
    });
}
navSlide();
```

if any one of you need HTML and CSS Code please inform me.

Comment: Why use `navLinks.array.forEach` instead of `navLinks.forEach` ??

Comment: Welcome Talha Dar, to get the most out of stackoverflow it is important to write short, precise and meaningful question titles. This increases the chance of people reading the question and getting input or a solution quickly. This is a good starting point https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask how

Comment: actually previously I got the error like this forEach is not a function with `navLinks.forEach` so I  used `navLinks.array.forEach`

Comment: well now my error is resolved by removing `.array` thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `querySelectorAll` is gonna return a NodeList so there is no need to specify "array": `navLinks.array.forEach` just use `navLinks.forEach` and your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
 const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
```

with:

```
const navLinks = [...document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li")];
```

(in case you always have these items in the dom otherwise you will get a syntax error)

and then try with:

```
navLinks.forEach(...)
```

Comment: Now i got this                                                                                                                    
error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'animation' of undefined
    at script.js:11
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>